# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Can you tell me why this is happening?

Tags: php

Please bear with me, I am new to PHP and this site.  I dont understand why this is throwing an error.  This code was moved from one server where it worked to a new one where it mostly works, aside from this error showing up in multiple places.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/jwhomeinspection/public_html/calendar/calendartable.php on line
>   184

```
   <?php 
       $lastAddress = '';
       $lastIns = '';
       $ttlAt = 0;
       foreach($apybtDay[$arrDate[1]] as $key => $value) { 


       if($lastIns != $value['assignedInspector']) { 
            echo '<br><div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">--'.$inspName[$value['assignedInspector']].'--</div>'; 

            $sResponse=curl_request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json',
                'origins='.urlencode($inspAddress[$value['assignedInspector']]).'&destinations='.urlencode($value['address'].' '.$value['zip']).'&mode=driving&units=imperial&sensor=false');
            $oJSON=json_decode($sResponse, true);

            echo '<div style="padding:3px;border:1px dashed #ccc;margin:5px;text-align:center;">';
            echo $oJSON['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
            echo ' / ';
            echo $oJSON['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
            echo '</div>';
       }


           if($lastAddress!='' && $lastIns == $value['assignedInspector']) {


            $sResponse=curl_request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json',
                'origins='.urlencode($lastAddress).'&destinations='.urlencode($value['address'].' '.$value['zip']).'&mode=driving&units=imperial&sensor=false');
            $oJSON=json_decode($sResponse, true);

            echo '<div style="padding:3px;border:1px dashed #ccc;margin:5px;text-align:center;">';
            echo $oJSON['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
            echo ' / ';
            echo $oJSON['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
            echo '</div>';

        }

        if($value['status'] == 'Pend') {
            echo '<div style="border:1px solid #F00; text-align:center;background-color:#'.$inspColor[$value['assignedInspector']].'" onClick="openAppt(\''.$value['aptId'].'\')" >';
            echo '<strong>Pending</strong><br>';    
        }else{
            if($value['memo'] == 'radon' || $value['memo'] == 'timeoff') {
                echo '<div style="text-align:center;background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#'.$inspColor[$value['assignedInspector']].',#'.$inspColor[$value['assignedInspector']].' 10px,#ebebeb 10px,#ebebeb 20px);" onClick="openAppt(\''.$value['aptId'].'\')" >';
            }else{
                echo '<div style="text-align:center;background-color:#'.$inspColor[$value['assignedInspector']].'" onClick="openAppt(\''.$value['aptId'].'\')" >';
            }
        }
        if($value['memo'] == 'radon') { echo '<strong>RADON PICKUP</strong><br>'; echo $value['address'].'<br>'.$value['city']; }
        elseif($value['memo'] == 'timeoff') { echo '<strong>TIME OFF / UNAVAIL</strong><br>'; echo $value['fullname'];}
        else{ echo $value['address'].'<br>'.$value['city']; $ttlAt++; }
        echo $value['address'].'<br>'.$value['city'];
        echo ' @ '.$timeSlot[$value['time']];
        $lastAddress = $value['address'].' '.$value['zip'];
        $lastIns = $value['assignedInspector'];
        echo '</div>'; 

        $dayTotal += $value['price'];

       } 

       echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:15px;padding:5px">Total: $'.number_format($dayTotal).' ('.$ttlAt.')</div>'; 
       $weekTotal += $dayTotal;
       $dayTotal = 0;
       $wkTtlAt += $ttlAt;
?>
```

Comment: Probably sometimes `$apybtDay[$arrDate[1]]` is not an array ?

Comment: `foreach($apybtDay[$arrDate[1]] as $key => $value) {` is a problem

Comment: Better replace `foreach($apybtDay[$arrDate[1]] as $key => $value) { ` as `foreach($apybtDay[$arrDate][1] as $key => $value) { ` and see what happened.